# Ruby undefined method `pair_push' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, null

I'm new to ruby

I created my own map class

```
class MyMap
    attr_accessor :key,:value
    def initialize
        self.key = []
        self.value = []
    end

    def pair_push(k, v)
        self.key.push(k)
        self.value.push(v)
    end

    ...     
end
```

And my own json object

```
class Json
    attr_accessor :index,:data
    def initialize
        index=MyMap.new
        data=MyMap.new
    end
    def create_index(_index, type, id)
        index.pair_push("_index", _index)
        index.pair_push("_type", type)
        index.pair_push("_id", id)
    end

    def add_to_data(attName, value)
        data.pair_push attName, value
    end
    ...
end
```

But when I try to use add_to_data 
`jsonDst.add_to_data(attributeName, arr[i])` I get the following error message

```
helloWorld.rb:66:in `add_to_data': undefined method `pair_push' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Note, before I invoke add_to_data I verify that `attributeName != nil && arr[i] != nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor you should use `@instance_variables`. In your `Json` class' constructor, when you refer to `data`, that's just an uninstantiated local variable. You should use `@data` instead. Same goes for `@index`:

```
class Json
    attr_accessor :index,:data
    def initialize
        @index=MyMap.new
        @data=MyMap.new
    end
    def create_index(_index, type, id)
        index.pair_push("_index", _index)
        index.pair_push("_type", type)
        index.pair_push("_id", id)
    end

    def add_to_data(attName, value)
        data.pair_push attName, value
    end
    ...
end
```

Here's how it works: http://ideone.com/mpLroq

Comment: It's actually valid, because of the `attr_accessor :index,:data`.